# Question about optimization of division code with type cast

Tags: c++, optimization, casting

Let's assume that I have code like this

```
int value, store;
store = value / 2;
```

As far as I know division is heavier than multiplication so, as an the optimization, I changed the code as follows:

```
store = value * 0.5f;
```

However, since value is an integer, I have to cast it

```
store = (int)(value * 0.5f);
```

But as far as I know, a type cast is also considered a heavy action. Therefore I made test for optimization with type cast with float and int

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

void main()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER StartingTime, EndingTime, ElapsedMicroseconds = { 0 };
    LARGE_INTEGER Frequency;
    int store[INT16_MAX] = { 0, }, value = 10;
    SetProcessPriorityBoost(GetCurrentProcess(), true);
    // get frequency
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency);

    // get starttime
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);
    for (int i = 0; i < INT16_MAX; i++)
        store[i] = (int)(value * 0.5f);
    // get endtime
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
    // get process time
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart *= 1000000;
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;
    std::cout << "Test Case 1 "<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "I * f with Type Cast : "<< ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart << std::endl << std::endl;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);
    for (int i = 0; i < INT16_MAX; i++)
        store[i] = value / 2;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart *= 1000000;
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;
    std::cout << "Test Case 2 " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "I / i with No Type Cast   : " << ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart << std::endl << std::endl;

    float store2 = 0.f;
    float value2 = 10.f;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);
    for (int i = 0; i < INT16_MAX; i++)
    {
        store2 = value2 * 0.5f;
        store[i] = (int)store2;
    }

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart *= 1000000;
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;
    std::cout << "Test Case 3 " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f * f with Type Cast   : " << ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart << std::endl << std::endl;


    QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);
    for (int i = 0; i < INT16_MAX; i++)
    {
        store2 = value2 / 2.f;
        store[i] = (int)store2;
    }

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart *= 1000000;
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;
    std::cout << "Test Case 4 " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f / f with Type Cast   : " << ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart << std::endl << std::endl;


    QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);
    for (int i = 0; i < INT16_MAX; i++)
    {
        store2 = value2 / 2;
        store[i] = (int)store2;
    }

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart *= 1000000;
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;
    std::cout << "Test Case 5 " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f / i with Type Cast   : " << ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart << std::endl << std::endl;

    return ;
}
```

```
Run 1

Test Case 2

I / i with No Type Cast   : 63

Test Case 3

f * f with Type Cast   : 56


Run2

Test Case 2

I / i with No Type Cast   : 48

Test Case 3

f * f with Type Cast   : 55
```

But the result says that some times case 2 is faster or sometime case 3 is faster. The other cases are too big.

What do you think about this? Do you think this test is suitable? Or did I made some mistake?

Comment: Did you switch on compile optimization options like -O3 or something?

Comment: @ArminMontigny No I didnt switch compile optimization But I will try now!

Comment: Really this is a waste of time. Turn on your compiler optmizations and trust it to make a better job of optimising your code than you can. If you really want to know what is happening then look at the assembly code that your compiler generates. You might be surprised.

Comment: @ArminMontigny I not sure why my visual studio do not have -03 option but I tried o2 and ox but the result is same. some times case 2 is faster or sometime case 3 is faster.

Comment: If you are dividing integers by 2 then `>>1` is the cheapest way to do it, any modern compiler should optimise divide by a constant power of 2 to a shift anyway

Comment: @Alan Birtles No compliant compiler will optimize divide to shift.  -1/2 == 0.  -1 >> 1 == -1. (Assuming an arithmetic shift).

Comment: @MartinBonner Oh.. I tried what Alan mentioned and i dont know but result seems better

Comment: @Distance1922 If you can live with the change in the result of dividing -1 (possibly because the input is actually always non-negative), it will (almost certainly) be faster.    But it's an optimization the compiler can't perform, because it can change the result, and the compiler can't tell that is safe.

Comment: @MartinBonner oh.... i just realize what you mean of dividing -1. It pretty doesn't seem to be the result I wanted. I think I have to revert what I've done

Comment: @MartinBonner -- it's not just -1. Right shift of **any** negative integer value produces undefined behavior.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ah.  That's not a problem for the compiler of course (it knows what the instruction set it is using will do).  It *is* a problem for the OP optimizing by using  shift at the source level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tight loops and small scale cases like these, it is usually best to look at the generated assembly (***and remember to turn on optimization***).

https://godbolt.org/z/a63g4y

If you look at the output - you will see that the compiler/optimizer did it's job and that the end result is the same.

Comment: @harold fixed it now, my bad

Comment: @darune wow there's no difference between divide and multiply?? lol thanks for this site I will look into it